# Drag and Drop images from another browser for imgur api?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, imgur

The following code is from a page that is dedicated exclusively for uploading images on **imgur.com**. This is a model from the net and you can **drag and drop images** from your **pc** whit no problems. My question is: What code i need to add so that i can **drag and drop images** from another browser?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf8">
<title>Upload</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>.

    <style>
    body {text-align: center; padding-top: 100px;}
    div { border: 10px solid black; text-align: center; line-height: 100px; width: 200px; margin: auto; font-size: 40px; display: inline-block;}
    #link, p , div {display: none}
    div {display: inline-block;}
    .uploading div {display: none}
    .uploaded div {display: none}
    .uploading p {display: inline}
    .uploaded #link {display: inline}
    </style>

<script>
window.ondragover = function(e) {e.preventDefault()}
window.ondrop = function(e) {e.preventDefault(); upload(e.dataTransfer.files[0]); }
function upload(file) {

    if (!file || !file.type.match(/image.*/)) return;

    document.body.className = "uploading";

    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("image", file);
    fd.append("key", "myapicode");
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "http://api.imgur.com/2/upload.json");
    xhr.onload = function() {

    document.querySelector("#link").href = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).upload.links.imgur_page;

    var test = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).upload.links.imgur_page;

    var dataString = 'content=' + test + '&page=something';
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "upload.img.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){
    }
    });
    document.body.className = "uploaded";
    }
    xhr.send(fd);
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div>DROP!<button onclick="document.querySelector('input').click()">Or click</button></div>
<input style="visibility:collapse;width:0px;" type="file" onchange="upload(this.files[0])">
<p>Uploading...</p>
<a id="link">Its online!!!</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why would you need to drag/drop images across browsers?

Comment: dear blender there are two ways to upload images: via computer and via LINK. So when you browse for a image.. you can grab it and drop it on this page so it can upload... YOU can recommend me something else :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all browsers support this, but Firefox will let you drag an image out of the browser to another browser or your computer, while Chrome does not allow you to drag an image out of the browser.

This [page](http://base64img.com/#encode) has a so called dropzone, open it in Chrome and open an image in Firefox, and you can drag the image straight from Firefox to Chrome, however it does not seem to work the other way around.

The [script](http://base64img.com/base64.js) is well commented and should give you some ideas, and the drag and drop stuff is basically set up like :

```
var dropzone;  
    dropzone = document.getElementById("dropzone");  
    dropzone.addEventListener("dragenter", dragin, false);
    dropzone.addEventListener("dragleave", dragout, false);
    dropzone.addEventListener("dragover", stopPropagation, false);
    dropzone.addEventListener("drop", drop, false);
```

Where `dragin`, `dragout`, `drop` etc. are functions called on those events that you will find in the script.